# How you calculate the age of the observable Universe if the acceleration expansion is not constant?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

What makes us believe that the Cosmological constant was the same in the past?

And if there is no way to prove this then could the age of our Universe be different from the current calculated value since the Universe could be expanded at a different rate in the past?

Even if the Cosmological constant value was different in the past how are the fail-safe limits calculated giving a finite tolerance to the current prediction of the age of our observable Universe?

Comment: You might want to read up on [quintessence models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessence_(physics)), which are a broad class of models in which the cosmological "constant" is actually a scalar field that evolves in time.  I'm not familiar with the most current models along these lines, but I suspect that they don't do any better than a true "constant" model in fitting the available data.

Comment: Keep in mind that the cosmological constant (CC) would have needed to be drastically different than from its value today, since until 'recently' the energy density in matter, and before that the one in radiation dominated strongly above the minuscule CC. As long as the CC was much smaller than these energy densities back then, it did not influence the evolution in any significant way in the early universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time evolution of a universe in which the cosmological constant is actually a variable can indeed be modeled on a computer, and the results compared to observational data. If we imagine a finite-element expansion model where the time variable is divided into discrete slices, then for any time slice the CC corresponding is updated in the model with a new value and the corresponding difference equations are solved. In this manner the expansion process is clanked forward one time increment at a time with a different value of the CC used at each increment.

Comment: Hi @Markoul11 - Are you familiar with the Friedmann equation? If not, I suggest you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation. If after you do that, if you still have questions, I will discuss them with you if you want.

Comment: @niels nielsen - For hypothetical projections beyond our observable region (which has no observable boundary), would that addition of dynamical fields described by scaphys not be necessary, or might some other observational data, such as the observation of a prevalent direction of motion (indicative of rotation in, & possibly beyond, our locality) suffice?

Comment: @edouard, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

It is, of course, possible to add dynamical fields to the theory which act as Dark Energy given an appropriate equation of state. In general, different models will indeed lead to a different age of the Universe.

In addition to its simplicity and the good agreement with a large array of observations, the cosmological constant is well-motivated by [Lovelock's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovelock%27s_theorem), which states that under a few reasonable assumptions, the gravitational field equations take the *unique* form

$$
a G_{\mu\nu} + b g_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu},
$$

with two constants $a$ and $b$. These are fixed by specifying the Newtonian gravitational constant and the cosmological constant. From this perspective, having *no* cosmological constant would actually be kind of fine-tuned.